# bobbing their hats at the chapel doors (author's use of the word)

Tags: meaning, hiberno-english

I'm having a really hard time understanding this phrase (from Iris Murdoch's story "Something Special"):

> “Don’t start on that thing again,” said her mother. “Sam’s a nice young fellow, and not like the run of the Jew-boys at all. He’d bring the children up Church of Ireland.”

> “At that,” said her uncle, “it’s better than the other lot with the little priest after them the whole time and **bobbing their hats at the chapel doors** so you can’t even have a peaceful ride on the tram. I’ve nothing against the Jews.”

> “Our Lord was a Jew,” said Yvonne.

> “Don’t be saying bold things like that!” said her mother.

First of all, **what are they doing with their hats**? Tipping them off? And most importantly, what does '**at the chapel doors**' mean - in the direction of the church or near the church entrance?

Thanks!

Comment: To [**bob**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bob) NOUN **1** Make a quick, short movement up and down. "At the chapel doors" – *Towards the chapel doors* (they are on a tram).

Comment: Probably doffing their hats then quickly replacing.

Comment: I would be inclined to interpret it as moving their heads up and down, in animated conversation.  https://youtu.be/mvhFs2bdRpE?t=47

Comment: If you are [Halloleute](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/bobbing-their-hats-at-the-chapel-doors.3718962/) on WordReference, you got an excellent answer from GreenWhiteBlue about 4 hours ago: "it is a custom among many Catholics when passing a church or chapel to make a sign of some kind to acknowledge the presence of the Eucharist, and to show reverence for it. Women may make the sign of the cross, while men wearing hats (and in the past, men always wore hats) would tip them/take them off"